# Summarize (count/freq) by treatment type where individuals could receive both treatments

Tags: r, dplyr

Say we have this data:

```
dat<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6),Rx=c(1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2))

   id Rx
1   1  1
2   1  2
3   2  1
4   2  2
5   3  1
6   4  1
7   4  1
8   5  2
9   6  2
10  6  2
```

Where Id is the subject id, and Rx is the treatment they received. So, there are repeated observations and the treatment may or may not be consistent per subject.

I want to be able to summarize how many subjects only received Rx 1, only received Rx 2, and how many received Rx 1 and 2.

I'd prefer a `dplyr` solution, but `data.table` and `base R` would be fine too. I thought something like:

```
dat %>%
  group_by(id,Rx) %>%
  unique() %>%
  ...something
```

The end result should be something like:

```
  Rx    Count
   1        2
   2        2
Both        2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the solution to generalize to more than two types of treatments?

Comment: The real problem only has two treatments so it isn't dire that it generalizes, but as a learning experience and for later application it would be appreciated if it generalized to >2 treatments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another generalized solution

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(indx = toString(sort(unique(Rx)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  count(indx)

# Source: local data table [3 x 2]
# 
#   indx n
# 1 1, 2 2
# 2    1 2
# 3    2 2
```

---

With `data.table`, similarly

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .(indx = toString(sort(unique(Rx)))), id][ , .N, indx]
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution does **not** generalize well to more than 2 treatments:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  distinct(id, Rx) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    trt1 = setequal(1, Rx), # change due to comment from @Marat Talipov
    trt2 = setequal(2, Rx),
    both = setequal(1:2, Rx)
    ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(id) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum), trt1:both)
```

This solution is shorter and does generalize to more than one treatment:

```
library(stringr)

dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    rx_list = str_c(sort(unique(Rx)), collapse = ",")
    ) %>%
  distinct(id) %>%
  count(rx_list)
```

Comment: Re first solution: You can use `setequal(XXX,dat$Rx)` (XXX could be 1, 2, or c(1,2)) instead of `%in%`

Comment: This is not completely correct if the treatment order wasn't the same. I.e. for this data set it will give a duplicate `dat<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6),Rx=c(2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,2))`

Comment: @DMC, for the second solution, if the order goes 1,2 vs. 2,1, separate groups are formed. 

Works if you change `rx_list` to `rx_list=str_c(sort(Rx),collapse=",")`

Comment: @AndrewTaylor - Thanks for catching that. Solution modified.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the output you have indicated, but it's base R, one-liner and general:

```
 table(do.call(function(...) paste(...,sep="_"),as.data.frame(table(dat)>0)))
 #FALSE_TRUE TRUE_FALSE  TRUE_TRUE 
     2          2          2
```

If the treatments are more then two, you have indicated all the possible combinations.

Comment: Or, for slightly different output `table(interaction(as.data.frame(table(dat)>0)))`